# Speeding up a portion of video leads to choppy transition

Tags: video, video-editor, editing, windows, windows-movie-maker

What I am trying to achieve is speed up a small portion of a video, lasting only about a second. I tried using Windows Movie Maker. What I did was import the video three times, then trim the three versions so that the first version ended at 16.06 seconds, the second started at 16.06 and ended at 17.54, and the third started at 17.54. Then I sped up the second by .25x.

The result is almost acceptable, but there's a tiny flicker when the second version starts and stops.

Does anyone know how I can get rid of the flicker, or if there's another editing program that is better suited to this task? I think it would be better if the sped up portion was sped up gradually.

Comment: What effect does this achieve that speeding up a copy of the video, then intercutting sections of that with sections of the original does not achieve? I can't quite picture what you're trying to do.

Comment: @JimMack If I understand you right, that's exactly what I did. I sped up one copy, sandwiched that copy between two normal-speed copies, and then trimmed all three copies so that they matched up. Is that what you had in mind?

Comment: Can you post a render of the video? Doesn't have to be the whole video, just the portions where the flicker/transition occurs.

Comment: @Mulvya I'm sorry, because of copyright issues I can't. It's like the video is buffering for a millisecond. Almost unnoticeable one time, but if I repeat the effect multiple times it becomes a problem.

Comment: Try trimming in and out by 1 frame i.e. start 2nd segment at the next frame after 16.06 and end one frame before 17.54.